# How to write SQL execution result:Field1 Field2 as shown in picture

Tags: sql, mysql

How to write a SQL statement to list only the names of 5 people and the average score of all subjects. *It does not have to be in a single statement.[image]

Comment: Use `LIMIT 5` to limit the query to 5 rows.

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 0):

A simple query in postgres could be like this

```
SELECT name , score FROM (
   SELECT id,AVG(score) AS score FROM scores_table 
   GROUP BY id 
) b
JOIN exam_taker_master using(id)
LIMIT 5
```